# Geometric idea behind equations of the form $|x-a|\pm|x-b|=c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, intuition, absolute-value

So let's say I want to solve $$|x-a|\pm|x-b|=c$$
Using the classic multiple cases approach, one can show that the solutions are given by $$x=\frac{a+b\pm c}2
$$
But how can one make sense of this geometrically?

(I think it has to do with the same thing as the solution to $|x-a|=c$, however here we add another distance term and so we take half of that quantity...)

Comment: I don't think this formula is true in all cases. For example if $|a-b|=c$ then for all points $x\in[a,b]$ fulfill the equation $|x-a|+|x-b|=c$. Depending on the parameters, $|x-a|+|x-b|=c$ can have no solutions, infinitely many solutions, or two solutions. In the degenerate case $a=b$ it may happen that there is only one solution.

Comment: Yes, but how to interpret all of those possible cases geometrically? By the way I'm more interested in the case where the solution is given by $x=\frac{a+b-c}{2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's look at $|x-a|+|x-b|=c$.

On the number line, $|x-a|$ is the distance between points $x$ and $a$. So $|x-a|+|x-b|$ is the sum of the distances from $x$ to $a$ and from $x$ to $b$. If $x$ is to the right of $a$ and $b$, we get this diagram (where the thick blue segment is  $|x-a|$ and the thinner red segment is  $|x-b|$):
[image: |x-a|+|x-b|]

We can shorten the segment between $a$ and $x$ and lengthen the segment between $b$ and $x$ by half the distance between $a$ and $b$, and we get this (where we now consider the green segment *twice*):
[image: Twice |x-(a+b)/2|]

If we let $c=|x-a|+|x-b|$ from the first diagram, the second diagram shows that also
$$c=2\left(x-\frac{a+b}2\right)$$
which leads us directly to
$$x=\frac{a+b-c}2$$
If we do the diagrams with $x$ to the left of $a$ and $b$, we get the sign of $c$ reversed and get instead
$$x=\frac{a+b+c}2$$
Thus,
$$x=\frac{a+b \pm c}2$$

---

Your other equation $|x-a|-|x-b|=c$ would be handled with $x$ between $a$ and $b$. The diagrams are similar, but I get the solution
$$x=\frac{a+b+c}2$$
without the minus before $c$. So if I am right, your offered formula is not quite right.

Comment: Can you please re-clarify the first part?

Comment: @MathGems: What exactly should I clarify? I am trying to avoid being too wordy.

Comment: My offered solution is correct, please see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=|x-a|-|x-b|%3Dc

Comment: @MathGems As you can see easily by plotting a graph, the equation $|x-a|-|x-b|=c$ only has one solution: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=|x-1|-|x%2B1| (Or no solutions, or infinitely many solutions - if you are interested in those cases, too.)

Comment: @MathGems: Here <http://i.stack.imgur.com/DngO9.jpg> is the graph for $y=|x−a|−|x−b|$ and for $y=c$ for $a=0, b=5, c=3$, showing that $x=\frac{a+b-c}2$ is *not* a solution (almost everywhere). The *only* solution is $x=\frac{a+b+c}2$ for $-|a−b|<c<|a−b|$. As Martin Sleziak pointed out, there are also cases for no or infinitely many solutions. Wolphram Alpha was simply wrong!